# Transmigration novel where a girl enters a novel she's been reading and becomes friend with the male lead

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel, young-adult

It is a historical novel, transmigration/reincarnation themed. This girl enters into a novel she read and becomes the male lead's childhood friend. I think the original friend died from falling off a tree or ladder while picking some fruit.

Later in the story, she does some yoga or exercise to calm herself down and the ml sees her and thinks she's some kind of witch doing some ritual(he doubted she's his friend since the start when she started acting strange/different).

The ml threatens to kill her if she doesn't explain who she is so she ends up telling him the truth, that she came inside this novel after his friend died and that she can tell what's going to happen in the future. She saved him before too, and that's what made him doubt her more, about how she ends up knowing when something bad is gonna happen.

He is a bit rough and tough, kind of stern. Maybe he is a Duke or something like that. She works as his assistant or something, maybe maid. Also I remember a scene where they are watching fireworks or some building getting demolished from his office window.

Edit- some scenes or details I remember:
It was a korean novel, translated to English.(about 40-45 chapters in)

The fl has a father in the novel. I think she maybe takes his place to work under ml.

The fl often makes tea for herself and ml(to help him relax I guess). I think the tea she made was very different from the og friend.

So far ml had zero interest in the fl romantically. He just thought he could use her for her knowledge of the novel.

I remember some details of the novel poster. It was very similar to manhwa style of art but a but more realistic physique. I think the fl was blonde and ml had black hair.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  (Approximately what year was "long ago?")

Comment: Was this a Korean novel, translated into English? If so, any idea if it was adapted into a manhwa? The "died after falling from a tree" bit reminds me of a manhwa I ran into a while back. I don't remember the name offhand, but it should be in my answer history.

Comment: Turns out that was *The Viridescent Tiara*, which doesn't match any of the other details. So that's not it.

Comment: @DavidW hello! I don't remember exactly but it was approx 2 years ago i guess. It maybe had more than 40-45 chapters(Might be more) and the author stopped updating for a while. It might still be with no update.

Comment: @qazmlpok Yes!! It was a korean novel, translated into English. Very similar plot to many manhwas. I might not be 100% accurate with my memory but the tree part I kind of remember. The og friend just died doing something related to climbing.

Comment: @qazmlpok I've read the viridescent crown and yes it's a different story:( but thankyou for looking into it! And as far as I know it was not adapted into a manhwa. I tried looking for it when I first read it but no.